# .htaccess rewriting rules for https, subdomains and friendly urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

As the title suggests, I want my urls to be:

1. Redirecting to HTTPS scheme for all urls
2. Redirecting subdomains to specific files
3. Rewriting user friendly links to url queries

What I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^ api.php [L]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^ admin.php [L]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ website.php [L]
```

This makes sure that when I type: admin.localhost, the file admin.php is loaded. Same for api.localhost. Normal localhost loads the website.php file. No problem here. Now, how do I implement friendly urls? And, when it comes to https, I know its not possible for localhost (or maybe it is, I dont know), but I have a website with ssl where I want to use this.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of tinkering, I came to a solution.

UPDATED TO REFLECT MY COMMENTS:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Remove the comments below to enable enforcing HTTPS
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ admin.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ website.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Okay this approach works only if the url looks like this: admin.localhost/some/parameter/here but if its just admin.localhost then i get the directory structure since i dont want to use an index file. how do i fix this?

Comment: okay i found the solution to THAT too. believe it or not, if I change ^(.+)$ to ^(.*)$, then this approach works.